# Even though the value of object is null, if( object_name == null) fails

Tags: nullpointerexception, null

Flight `flightToUpdate` = null;
                        // Assign value to the variables if the airport code exists
                        flightToUpdate = DatabaseOperations.getFlightByFlightNumber(columns[0]);

```
                    System.out.println(flightToUpdate);

                    if (flightToUpdate == null) {// If the location for the given airport code is not present, it needs to be added
                        Flight flightToAdd = new Flight();
                        flightToAdd.setFilghtNumber(columns[0]);
                        flightToAdd.setDepartureAirport(columns[1]);
                        flightToAdd.setDestinationAirport(columns[2]);
                        flightToAdd.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(columns[3]));
                        flightToAdd.setDatetime(df.parse(columns[4]));
                        flightToAdd.setPlane(columns[5]);
                        flightToAdd.setSeatsTaken(Integer.parseInt(columns[6]));

                        //Add to database
                        DatabaseOperations.AddFlight(flightToAdd);

                    } else { 
                        System.out.println("Success4");
                        DatabaseOperations.UpdateFlight(flightToUpdate);
                    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Is it C++ code or C# one?

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve] by completing it.  And tag it with the appropriate programming language.